# Emacs ESS - weird characters in AC tooltip

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, ess

Am using `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)
 of 2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian`, have `ess-20160602.203`.
My problem is AC tool-tip has some weird characters like -[image]
Any help will be appreciated to remove those weird characters

Comment: It has something to do with utf-8 and iso-latin-1-unix (my guess).....

Comment: Sorry to bother everybody, it had amazingly simple solution...`(set-language-environment "UTF-8") in `.emacs`...and simple things are the one hard to find....